# How can i display the table row that just got clicked, on another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a website where you can see buildings on a map and where users can click on a table row ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsGpx.png)) (where informations about the building is shown) to get redirected to the map page. Additionally, and thats where i'm stuck, the clicked table row should appear on the first page ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCokp.png)).

So the question is: how can i display the table row that just got clicked, on another page?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index of the row that is clicked as props

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's difficult to answer to this question since it's very generic, I'll try to assume that you are missing the basic approach and need a starting point on how resolve this. Once you clicked on the row, you can pass the data to the new URL. Assuming that you are calling a new page, the row should be wrapped in an anchor element and in this case the data can be passed with a GET request, included in the URL. You can have a look to the [W3school website page talking about GET method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)
to learn more about it.
If you are trying to do this as a single page application with react instead, start looking at React documentation on [how components and props work](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) to pass props down to other components.
Hope you find this helpful!